# Power BI report based on user input

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to get a report to display results based on the input of the user. This will be used online by the user not in the desktop app so we cannot use a parameter. Also need to be able to change input as needed. What we are looking for is not to show any data at all in a table until the user inputs the username to lookup. Think of it like the way a slider acts, but only using the search box. we do not want to show the list of usernames, the user must already have that information. So the main thing is show nothing until input is made, once made show username information (statistics). 
Is this possible?

Comment: You might be able to populate a column with all usernames, hide it, but then use the user input as a filter. But there is no "free text" input capability in Power BI. What are you actually trying to do? This would probably be implemented much cheaper and easier in a custom web app. What is to stop this user typing in random names and extracting all info anyway?

Comment: It's not that we don't want them to find usernames, the users that will access the the site will most likely have a list of all usernames. This is for classes. tutor is the user inputting the students username and different stats show up for that student. Not showing username list is for viewing purposes. there are thousands of usernames. I guess if NEED be we can show them but back to display no reports until username input/selected.

Comment: This sounds like a completely normal usage of a slicer filter. Yes there will be a large list but you can used "Advanced" filtering to type in a name. It works but it's clunky. Or you could search custom visuals but there's always a risk the custom visual would stop working or become unsupported

Comment: Try https://okviz.com/smart-filter/ it a nice slicer that allows you to type in the search box. You can turn off the 'buy pro' nag ware in the formatting options

Comment: For this sort of requirement of not displaying data and having user input would be best suited for SSRS

Comment: Have a look at row level security: e.g.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-rls